# Taking multiple select query results and making differences columns for a single row

Tags: sql, db2

I have a simple select query in db2 that works but I'm trying to find a way to turn result records into columns for one result record. I have:

```
SELECT item_id, t2.item_title, t2.item_data
FROM item t1 
INNER JOIN title t2
ON  t1.item_id = t2.item_id
```

This gives

```
item_id | item_title  |   item_data
-----------------------------------
123         Main          Test Title
123         Sub           Subtitle
```

Is there a way I can alter the select to get the data for each title type as a column and only return one row?

so I want to get main and sub as their own column and return:

```
item_id | main_data  |   sub_data
-----------------------------------
123      Test Title      Subtitle
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 Pivot (rows to columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492501/db2-pivot-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pivot operation, and a cross-platform way to achieve it looks like this:

Step 1: break the data into its own columns for main and sub:

```
SELECT 
  t1.item_id, 
  CASE WHEN t2.item_title = 'Main' THEN t2.item_data END as main_title,
  CASE WHEN t2.item_title = 'Sub' THEN t2.item_data END as sub_title
FROM item t1 
INNER JOIN title t2
ON  t1.item_id = t2.item_id
```

Step 2: squish the results down to one row, getting rid of the nulls using group/max

```
SELECT 
  t1.item_id, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.item_title = 'Main' THEN t2.item_data END) as main_title,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.item_title = 'Sub' THEN t2.item_data END) as sub_title
FROM item t1 
INNER JOIN title t2
ON  t1.item_id = t2.item_id
GROUP BY t1.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pivot operation,you can try this
WITH Opening AS(
        SELECT 
            item_id, 
            t2.item_title, 
            t2.item_data
        FROM item t1 
        INNER JOIN title t2 ON
            t1.item_id = t2.item_id)
SELECT 
     item_id,Main ,Sub
     PIVOT(
        item_data
        FOR item_title IN([Main],[Sub])
     ) as PivotTable
FROM Opening;