# DB2 Pivot equivalent

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Hoping someone can help, I am working with a db2 database and I am trying to pivot some data to turn it from rows to columns. My data table looks like this

| Key1 | Key2 | Date | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Key1 | 01/01/2020 | ABC | TEST1 |
| One | Key1 | 01/01/2020 | DEF | TEST2 |
| One | Key1 | 01/01/2020 | JKL | TEST3 |
| One | Key2 | 01/01/2020 | GHI | TEST3 |
| One | Key2 | 02/01/2020 | ABC | TEST3 |
| Two | Key1 | 01/01/2020 | ABC | TEST4 |
| Two | Key1 | 01/01/2020 | DEF | TEST5 |
| Tow | Key2 | 01/01/2020 | GHI | TEST6 |

I would like my results table to look like this

| Key1 | Key2 | Date | ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Key1 | 01/01/2020 | TEST1 | TEST2 | TEST3 |  |
| One | Key2 | 01/01/2020 |  |  | TEST 3 |  |
| One | Key2 | 02/01/2020 | TEST3 |  |  |  |
| Two | Key1 | 01/01/2020 | TEST4 | TEST5 |  |  |
| Two | Key2 | 01/01/2020 |  |  | TEST6 |  |

I know there is the pivot statement in SQL and i have tried this solution "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492501/db2-pivot-rows-to-columns" but it rolls up everything in Key1 and does not give me the table i would like, so using that solution i only see one row key key1 which is not what i want. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select key1, key2, date,
       max(case when type = 'ABC' then value end) as abc,
       max(case when type = 'DEF' then value end) as def,
       max(case when type = 'GHI' then value end) as ghi,
       max(case when type = 'JFK' then value end) as jfk
from t
group by key1, key2, date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=e3b0ef6fe021def302fae28349a1052f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, does the order of the group matter?

Comment: Group by I mean

Comment: @DATAMART . . . If you mean the order of the keys in the `GROUP BY` or `SELECT`, then no.

Comment: Even through Key 2 is in the group by, in only seeing one row as per key 1 rather then three rows as per key 2

Comment: @DATAMART . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  It works.