# DB2/AS400 SQL Pivot

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have a problem with pivot tables ....
I don't understand what to do ...
My table is as follows:

```
|CODART|MONTH|QT  |
|------|-----|----|
|ART1  |1    |100 |
|ART2  |1    |30  |
|ART3  |1    |30  |
|ART1  |2    |10  |
|ART4  |2    |40  |
|ART3  |4    |50  |
|ART5  |4    |60  |
```

I would like to get a summary table by month:

```
|CODART|1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |8  |9  |10 |11 |12 |
|------|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
|ART1  |100|10 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|ART2  |30 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|ART3  |30 |   |   |50 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 
|ART4  |   |2  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|ART5  |   |   |   |60 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|TOTAL |160|12 |   |110|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

Too many requests? :-)

Thanks for the support

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DB2 Pivot equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053075/db2-pivot-equivalent)

Comment: the last row of totals is missing
I can't figure out how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH MYTAB (CODART, MONTH, QT) AS 
(
VALUES 
  ('ART1', 1, 100)
, ('ART2', 1,  30)
, ('ART3', 1,  30)
, ('ART1', 2,  10)
, ('ART4', 2,  40)
, ('ART3', 4,  50)
, ('ART5', 4,  60)
)
SELECT 
  CASE GROUPING (CODART) WHEN 0 THEN CODART ELSE 'TOTAL' END AS CODART
, SUM (CASE MONTH WHEN  1 THEN QT END) AS "1"
, SUM (CASE MONTH WHEN  2 THEN QT END) AS "2"
, SUM (CASE MONTH WHEN  3 THEN QT END) AS "3"
, SUM (CASE MONTH WHEN  4 THEN QT END) AS "4"
---
, SUM (CASE MONTH WHEN 12 THEN QT END) AS "12"
FROM MYTAB T
GROUP BY ROLLUP (T.CODART)
ORDER BY GROUPING (T.CODART), T.CODART
```

| CODART | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ART1 | 100 | 10 |  |  |  |
| ART2 | 30 |  |  |  |  |
| ART3 | 30 |  |  | 50 |  |
| ART4 |  | 40 |  |  |  |
| ART5 |  |  |  | 60 |  |
| TOTAL | 160 | 50 |  | 110 |  |